# Table refusing to be centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My table isn't being centered no matter what packages and formats I try.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{xxxxx}
\author{xxxxxxxx }
\date{July 2019}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
{
\scalebox{.79}{{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| ccccccccc |}
\toprule
Metric Date & Metric Values &  Metric Rank & VIX Date &  VIX Values &  VIX Rank & metric rank & vix rank & timedelta \\
\midrule
  2017-06-20 & 0.3217 &  1 &  2018-02-05 & 37.32 &   1 &  10 & 1 &  0 days \\
  2016-12-19 & 0.3194 &  2 &  2018-12-24 & 36.07 &  2  & 10 & 6 &    1 days \\
  2017-09-18 & 0.3193 &  3 &  2018-02-08 & 33.46 &  3  &  9 &   9 &  1 days \\
  2016-12-27 & 0.2993 & 4 &  2018-12-26 &  30.41 &  4  & 10 & 3 &  3 days \\
  2017-06-05 & 0.2874 & 5 &  2018-12-27 & 30.41 & 5 &  10 & 8 & 4 days \\
  2017-05-23 & 0.2708 & 6 &  2018-02-06 & 29.98 & 6 &  9 & 2 & 5 days \\
  2017-08-25 & 0.2461 & 7 &  2018-12-28 & 29.96 & 7 &  9 & 4 & 7 days \\
  2017-08-24 & 0.2398 & 8 &  2018-02-09 & 29.06 & 8 &  9 & 5 & 8 days \\
  2018-12-19 & 0.2391 & 9 &  2018-12-20 & 28.38 & 9 &  9 & 7 & 9 days \\
  2018-02-05 & 0.2317 & 10 & 2016-02-11 & 28.14 & 10 & 3 & 1 & 140 days \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
}}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the origin of the .79 scaling factor?

Comment: @egreg Well so I originally downloaded this in tex format from pandas in python

Comment: Please, add the document class and also whatever you use to set the page parameters, if you do.

Comment: @egreg Ok, just did.

Comment: Try removing the `\centering` command from the scaled box.  That box doesn't specify a width, so it's unclear to me how the width of the `tabular` will be taken into account, and in fact what the actual width is before scaling -- presumably, since it's scaled, it is wider than the text width.  I can't test, so this is a guess.

Comment: `scale=.79` is just an arbitrary guess; the table is obviously oversized (by 92pt). You have spaces creeping in and the headers are too long: you should use something like `width=\textwidth`, but the result will be very poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling a table should be the very last resort. The `.79` scaling factor is just a wild (and wrong) guess, that leaves an oversized object that of course is not centered and sticks out in the right margin.

First fix the long headers that waste much of the space; then squeeze the intercolumn space; it's handy to use `tabular*`, leaving the computations to TeX.

I left (commented out) `\small`. Try with it to see if the table looks better.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{xxxxx}
\author{xxxxxxxx }
\date{July 2019}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
%\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Metric} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{VIX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{rank} & timedelta \\
\cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{4-6} \cmidrule{7-8}
Date & Values &  Rank & Date & Values & Rank & metric & vix\\
\midrule
2017-06-20 & 0.3217 &  1 & 2018-02-05 & 37.32 &  1 & 10 & 1 &   0 days \\
2016-12-19 & 0.3194 &  2 & 2018-12-24 & 36.07 &  2 & 10 & 6 &   1 days \\
2017-09-18 & 0.3193 &  3 & 2018-02-08 & 33.46 &  3 &  9 & 9 &   1 days \\
2016-12-27 & 0.2993 &  4 & 2018-12-26 & 30.41 &  4 & 10 & 3 &   3 days \\
2017-06-05 & 0.2874 &  5 & 2018-12-27 & 30.41 &  5 & 10 & 8 &   4 days \\
2017-05-23 & 0.2708 &  6 & 2018-02-06 & 29.98 &  6 &  9 & 2 &   5 days \\
2017-08-25 & 0.2461 &  7 & 2018-12-28 & 29.96 &  7 &  9 & 4 &   7 days \\
2017-08-24 & 0.2398 &  8 & 2018-02-09 & 29.06 &  8 &  9 & 5 &   8 days \\
2018-12-19 & 0.2391 &  9 & 2018-12-20 & 28.38 &  9 &  9 & 7 &   9 days \\
2018-02-05 & 0.2317 & 10 & 2016-02-11 & 28.14 & 10 &  3 & 1 & 140 days \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some further work for reducing a bit more the column widths: removing repeated information is always good. Thanks to Fran for suggesting.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{xxxxx}
\author{xxxxxxxx }
\date{July 2019}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
%\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Metric} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{VIX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{rank} &
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} time $\delta$ \\ (days) \end{tabular}} \\
\cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{4-6} \cmidrule{7-8}
Date & Values &  Rank & Date & Values & Rank & metric & vix\\
\midrule
2017-06-20 & 0.3217 &  1 & 2018-02-05 & 37.32 &  1 & 10 & 1 &   0 \\
2016-12-19 & 0.3194 &  2 & 2018-12-24 & 36.07 &  2 & 10 & 6 &   1 \\
2017-09-18 & 0.3193 &  3 & 2018-02-08 & 33.46 &  3 &  9 & 9 &   1 \\
2016-12-27 & 0.2993 &  4 & 2018-12-26 & 30.41 &  4 & 10 & 3 &   3 \\
2017-06-05 & 0.2874 &  5 & 2018-12-27 & 30.41 &  5 & 10 & 8 &   4 \\
2017-05-23 & 0.2708 &  6 & 2018-02-06 & 29.98 &  6 &  9 & 2 &   5 \\
2017-08-25 & 0.2461 &  7 & 2018-12-28 & 29.96 &  7 &  9 & 4 &   7 \\
2017-08-24 & 0.2398 &  8 & 2018-02-09 & 29.06 &  8 &  9 & 5 &   8 \\
2018-12-19 & 0.2391 &  9 & 2018-12-20 & 28.38 &  9 &  9 & 7 &   9 \\
2018-02-05 & 0.2317 & 10 & 2016-02-11 & 28.14 & 10 &  3 & 1 & 140 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This made me tear up with joy. That my fine feathered friend is a work of art.

Comment: Nice (+1). I will use also "Time $\delta$ (days)" in the last column and remove "days" in every row and for dates the format `yyyy/mm/dd`  (take almost the same space but look like a bit  more readable).

Comment: @Fran “Time δ” or “Timedelta” depends on the traditions in the field; possibly “days” can be removed; the format 2019-07-25 for the date is the ISO approved; slashes are not in the standard.

Comment: @egreg Fortunately, in my field, at the moment nobody cares about the ISO 8601 `:)`